# AFNetworking downloading a file despite getting 304 Server response

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

So I want to download a file from a webserver even though the server response is 304 Not Modified. 
I use the AFURLSessionManager's `downloadTaskWithRequest: progress: destination: completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)` method which works fine for files which aren't modified. However if the server response is 304, it seems there is no valid filePath in completionHandler block and the `error` says "Request failed: not modified (304)".

I tried configurating AFURLSessionManager's requestCachePolicy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData but that doesn't help: although filePath is set, the data can't be reconstructed from this filepath.

Can someone help me by maybe specifying what exactly would be the best practice for downloading a file with AFNetworking and Server response 304. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the problem. I don't have to set the requestCachePolicy of the NSURLSessionConfiguration. I always added IF_MODIFIED_SINCE_HEADER to the request parameter of `downloadTaskWithRequest:`. Omitting this, it works.